# Python find obj value based on condition within dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

I get below json data from a python request:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "virtual-machine-1",
            "guest": "Microsoft Windows Server 2016 (64-bit)",
            "status": "green",
            "id": "567890-004",
        },
        {
            "name": "virtual-machine-2",
            "guest": "CoreOS Linux (64-bit)",
            "status": "green",
            "id": "567890-005",
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get "id" values of all dictionaries based on the "name" values.

I have seen solutions for finding values based on keys but not on a conditional basis within same dictionary and iterating it for multiple dictionaries. Appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you trying to get all values of "id" from the results dictionary, where name == some string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's re-keying off the id:

```
>>> {result['id']: result['name'] for result in data['results']}
{'567890-004': 'virtual-machine-1', '567890-005': 'virtual-machine-2'}
```

This technique is called a *dictionary comprehension*.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Got what I needed and get to know about the dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {result['name']: result['id'] for result in request.dict['results'] if 'name' in result}
# request.dict is the name of the object that contains the list "results"
```

Comment: will only return id if the result has a name key also

Answer (score 1):

Convert your json to a list of dictionaries. Then just use short-hand for statement.

```
results = [
{ "name": "virtual-machine-1",
            "guest": "Microsoft Windows Server 2016 (64-bit)",
            "status": "green",
            "id": "567890-004"},
{"name": "virtual-machine-2",
            "guest": "CoreOS Linux (64-bit)",
            "status": "green",
            "id": "567890-005"}
]

id = [x['id'] for x in results if x['name'] == "virtual-machine-1"]
print id    # prints 567890-004

id = [x['id'] for x in results if x['name'] == "virtual-machine-2"]
print id    # prints 567890-005
```

Comment: I am having hard time writing a formatted comment and hence lot of edits. Sorry

While looking at your solution, id is returning '[]' where there is no match found.<br/>

eg., there is no 'virtual-machine-3' above and if I try<br/>

id = [x['id'] for x in results if x['name'] == "virtual-machine-3"]
print id    # prints [] <br/> 

I expect an error since if I validate the result with 'assert id is not None'    before using it somewhere, it returns 'True' for an empty value.